# Optimize SQL query using count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use ASP.NET Membership and on top of that I have added some tables with one to many relationship with the users.

One user has many Pens, Notebooks, etc.

I am coding a custom membership provider and have modified the select query to retrieve all the information about the user plus the number of pens that the user has and the total number of "tools", but the query obviously performs catastrophically.
Is there anyway to get that information?
This is what I have tried:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT  m.Email, m.PasswordQuestion, m.IsApproved, m.CreateDate, m.LastLoginDate,
        u.LastActivityDate, m.LastPasswordChangedDate, u.UserId, m.IsLockedOut, 
        m.LastLockoutDate, CAST(m.Comment as nvarchar(max)) as Comment, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT cl.Id) AS NumberOfPens, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT cf.Id)+
             COUNT(DISTINCT cm.Id) +
             COUNT(DISTINCT ce.Id) +
             COUNT(DISTINCT cl.Id) +
             COUNT(DISTINCT cp.Id) +
             COUNT(DISTINCT csl.Id)+
             COUNT(DISTINCT cs.Id) +
             COUNT(DISTINCT cshl.Id) AS NumberOfTools
FROM  aspnet_Membership AS m 
      INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AS u ON m.UserId = u.UserId 
      INNER JOIN Pens AS cf ON u.UserId = cf.Owner 
      INNER JOIN Notebooks AS cm ON u.UserId = cm.Owner 
      INNER JOIN Rulers AS ce ON u.UserId = ce.Owner 
      INNER JOIN Calculators AS cl ON u.UserId = cl.Owner 
      CROSS JOIN aspnet_Applications AS a
GROUP BY u.UserId, m.Email, m.PasswordQuestion, m.IsApproved, 
         m.CreateDate, m.LastLoginDate, u.LastActivityDate, 
         m.LastPasswordChangedDate, m.IsLockedOut, m.LastLockoutDate, 
         CAST(m.Comment as nvarchar(max))

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

9 minutes 11 seconds for 91 users!

Comment: Yes, I know I suck at DB. But I would really like to have those numbers, but I dont have a clue as how to get them

Comment: Which SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a quick hit, take out that `cross join` at the very end--you aren't using it and it's just multiplying your results and slowing things down.

Additionally, you can just do the counts before joining, which will save `group by` and allow the RDBMS to parallelize the query, like so:

```
SELECT     
    m.Email, 
    m.PasswordQuestion, 
    m.IsApproved, 
    m.CreateDate, 
    m.LastLoginDate, 
    u.LastActivityDate, 
    m.LastPasswordChangedDate, 
    u.UserId, 
    m.IsLockedOut, 
    m.LastLockoutDate, 
    CAST(m.Comment as nvarchar(max)) as Comment, 
    PenCount AS NumberOfPens, 
    PenCount + NotebookCount + RulerCount + CalculatorCount AS NumberOfTools
FROM
    aspnet_Membership AS m 
    INNER JOIN aspnet_Users AS u ON 
        m.UserId = u.UserId 
    INNER JOIN (select owner, count(1) as PenCount from Pens group by owner) AS cf ON 
        u.UserId = cf.Owner 
    INNER JOIN (select owner, count(1) as NotebookCount from Notebooks group by owner) AS cm ON 
        u.UserId = cm.Owner 
    INNER JOIN (select owner, count(1) as RulerCount from Rulers group by owner) AS ce ON 
        u.UserId = ce.Owner 
    INNER JOIN (select owner, count(1) as CalculatorCount from Calculators group by owner) AS cl ON 
        u.UserId = cl.Owner
```

Note that if a user may not have *all* tools, you'll want to do `LEFT` joins in lieu of `inner` joins, and then wrap all of the `*Count` columns with `coalesce(Count, 0)`.

Comment: Ok. I am trying that now. Thanks!

Comment: @BCartolo - I just edited this query to be a little quicker, as well. Let me know what you find :)

Comment: @BCartolo, you MAY need to change to LEFT JOINs on the tables associated with count(1).  If you have an owner that is NOT used within Pens, but does in Notebooks, Rulers, etc, it will be left out.  By doing a LEFT JOIN to the "count" aliases will ensure that all members will be included with their respective counts, even if a count is only in one such sub-category count.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I will try it now (I was out for lunch :D)

Comment: Every user have at least one tool of each type. This is what SLQ says::
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 141 ms,  elapsed time = 184 ms.
It is better than 9 minutes, right? I will try the other option

Comment: 184ms is just a *little* better than 9 minutes :)

Comment: Ok I changed the inner join by left so i get even the users with no tools. Thanks all for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  m.Email, m.PasswordQuestion, m.IsApproved, m.CreateDate, m.LastLoginDate,
        u.LastActivityDate, m.LastPasswordChangedDate, u.UserId, m.IsLockedOut, 
        m.LastLockoutDate, CAST(m.Comment as nvarchar(max)) as Comment,
        penCount,
        notebookCount + rulerCount + calculatorCount AS toolCount
FROM    aspnet_Membership m
JOIN    aspnet_Users u
ON      u.userId = m.userId
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    pens
        WHERE   owner = u.UserId
        ) p (penCount)
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    notebooks
        WHERE   owner = u.UserId
        ) n (notebookCount)
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    rulers
        WHERE   owner = u.UserId
        ) r (rulerCount)
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    calculators
        WHERE   owner = u.UserId
        ) c (calculatorCount)
```

Comment: This option works as fast as the other. But the other one was posted first. Thanks anyways!